# private bucket S3 access support AWS signature version 4

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, configuration, authorization

I am trying to access with a reverse proxy the content of a private bucket on my amazon services but it seems that the fact that the instance is running in Frankfurt doesnt let me access it. This is the nginx.conf:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;
    server {
        listen 80;
    server_name ec2-id.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com;  

    rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;


}
server {

    listen 443;
    server_name ec2-id.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com;  

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/ssl_access.log;

    location ^~ / {
     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass          https://server.com;
            proxy_read_timeout  30;

        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
    }

        location /one/service {
        proxy_pass http://beanstalk-1.3tkffhitv2.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/;
         proxy_read_timeout  30;
         proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
         proxy_ssl_verify off;

        }
        location   /privateproxy  {
            set $s3_bucket        'bucketname.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com';
            set $algorithm      '?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
            set $aws_access_key '&X-Amz-Credential=MY_KEY/20160322/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request';
            set $date       '&X-Amz-Date=20160322T201207Z';
            set $url_expires    '&X-Amz-Expires=604800';
            set $signature      '&X-Amz-Signature=$arg_st';
            set $SignedHeaders  '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host';

      set $url_full         '$algorithm$aws_access_key$date$url_expires$SignedHeaders$signature';


      proxy_http_version     1.1;
      proxy_set_header       Host $s3_bucket;
      proxy_set_header       Authorization "";
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
      proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
      proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
      proxy_buffering        off;
      proxy_intercept_errors on;

      resolver                8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
      resolver_timeout       10s;

      proxy_pass              http://$s3_bucket/$url_full;      }           
  }

  }
```

the browser returns an xml that has an error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code>
<Message>
Query-string authentication version 4 requires the X-Amz-Algorithm, X-Amz-Credential, X-Amz-Signature, X-Amz-Date, X-Amz-SignedHeaders, and X-Amz-Expires parameters.
</Message>
```

I have tried running "aws configure set default.s3.signature_version s3v4"
and updating my client etc. but it still occurs.
Any idea?

Comment: Among other things, `$url_full` is not being built out of the correct components for [Signature V4 Query Strings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html).  For example, `AWSAccessKeyId=` is replaced with `X-Amz-Credential=` *and the value is made up of more than just the access key*.  However, there's too much unexplained magic going on here (how does `$arg_st` actually get set, for example?) to identify all of what may need to be different before this works in a V4-only region.

Comment: thank you for that! I did the changes according to the documentation. Signature generation is a bit complex though

Comment: Check the documentation again.  `X-Amz-Expires=` expects number of seconds the signature is valid past `X-Amz-Date`, max value 604800 (7 days).  You are using epoch time, as required for V2.  The `/` characters in `X-Amz-Credential` must be percent (url-) encoded as `%2F`.

Comment: Also you are doubling-up the `&` in the URL you're building.  They're in the original variables, and they're also in the final string.

Comment: you are so right! thank you again :D

Comment: I, for one, would definitely like to see how that signature is generated (as a reference for my own work).  Might be useful to others, too, if you share it.